# Mathematical notation to represent dimensions

Tags: notation

I'm writing for scientific journal and thesis and I was wondering if I'm using the correct mathematical notations. If I have defined $D_1$ as the first dimension in a $n$-dimensional database, then, is it the correct way of writing $((D_i)_{i=2}^n)$ to represent the remaining dimensions in the $n$-dimensional database? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have seen ${(A_b)}_{b \in I}$, where $I$ is some index set, but in your case, why not simply write $(D_2,\ldots,D_n)$?

Comment: Also, another alternative more in line with what you suggested, $(D_i)_{i=2,\dots,n}$.

Comment: I have tried several way of representing the remaining dimensions, and I'm trying to see which one would be the most logical. So, if I were to define them as what you have suggested $(D_i)_{i=2,...,n}$, then later on in my writing, when I need to formulate my case scenario relating to the dimensions, is it correct if I formulate it this way. For example: $Q.D_1 \lt R.D_1$ and $(Q.D_i)_{i=2,...,n} \le (R.D_i)_{i=2,...,n}$. Does this make sense?

Comment: I can't possibly answer that. In your expressions above, I have no idea what "dimensions" $D_i$ are (integers?), what kind of objects does $Q, R$ stands for, what kind of operation and relation are donted by $.$ and $\lt$.

Comment: Also, instead of what your wrote, I would simply write $Q . D_i \leq R . D_i$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$, if that is what you meant by the second expression, and $\leq$ is not some special relation you defined on $n$-tuples of whatever objects $Q.D_i$ might be.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention beforehand that the dimensions are all assumed to be integers. Thanks for your responses, it does help with what I'm trying to do, and I think that I will use the one that you have suggested as above. Thank you.